# Why can't I see any indicators from Syntastic?

Tags: vim, syntastic

I'm trying to use vim for my project. In order to do that I would like to get real-time feedback from eslint (like I get in sublime with [SublimeLinter-eslint](https://github.com/roadhump/SublimeLinter-eslint)) and am therefore trying to get [Syntastic](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic) working.

Everything seems to be set up properly but I'm not getting any indicators. Am I missing something? `:SyntasticInfo` seems to show the correct expected output but clearly I should be getting some sort of error on line 66 in this screenshot.

[image: eslint is enabled but not validating]

Comment: Try the plugin's issue tracker.

Comment: @romainl are you saying that I have it set up properly? Because thats really a part of my question - I don't know if I should talk about it on the issue tracker because I don't know if this is an issue or if I'm doing something wrong

Comment: Just to ask the obvious -- have you saved the file yet?

Comment: also, depending on your eslint config that line might or might not trigger an error. When I do something similar in an existing project I have, it just tells me I'm missing a semicolon, something which you're not using

Comment: try something more extreme, like dropping the comma at the end of line 57

Comment: @DavidWoods yup, saved the file (though sublime doesn't require this) and tried removing the comma, nothing shows up. Theses are all errors that show up in sublime's eslint